How to change the colour of a selection in Gimp
I have checked all the guides but i guess i'm missing something. I spent hours clicking around in the GIMP app.  sooo...I was able to create my custom selection. I choose my desired colour using the color picker (I choose navy blue as my fg color)
I choose the Bucket fill.
But how do I actually apply the colour?
I saw other guides where they seem to just click and it becomes the new color, however in my case it doesn't change the colour.
However, weirdly, I can apply a pattern fill successfuly just by clicking.
Does any gimp expert have any idea where I've gone wrong? It would be very much appreciated!
Emma


Just to say, I did have fill type with FG color fill selected, and I click my selection, it doesn't make it blue. I just changed to pattern fill to illustrate that it is actually working as expected, contrary to FG colour fill.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The actions you are describing should work. Can you share a screenshot of your entire screen?  Don't take a photo with your phone. Thanks.

Is there a way to add a video? Then it's clearer what I'm doing

You can just make a decent screenshot (not a crooked photo...) showing the whole UI (title bar included), even with Gimp itself: File > Create > Screenshot

If your image is color-indexed (see title bar) then read this.

You can't add videos here, but you can add animated GIFs.  If you have screen capture software, you can use it to create a GIF.
